# Create a socket.io server and connect it from clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a VPS and I installed node.js and socket.io libraries, Now I want to host my node.js app on the VPS so clients can connect and listen the server via the VPS IP address. Now this is my code I wrote, It works fine when the server and clients be on localhost, but When I put the ip address of the VPS, it's show me an error "This site can’t be reached , took too long to respond." Can any one check the code and tell me what is the problem ?

Server.js

```
const server = require('http').createServer();

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {

    console.log('New Client Connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => { });

});

server.listen(3000);
```

Client.html

```
<script src="http://ip-address:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

var socket = io.connect('http://ip-address:3000');

socket.on('event_name',(data) => {
       console.log(data);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Node-http-server) sample code provided by [socket.io](https://socket.io).

```js
// app.js
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: OK, This works fine in case of localhost, But if I implement it to connect an external ip address, it did't worked !!

Comment: Try to use `var socket = io('ws://ip-address:3000');` instead of `var socket = io('http://localhost');`